# max-width used for flex container instead of fit-content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

If you run the code snippet below you can see that the width used for the top `<div>` is `200px` (`max-width`). But in reality it doesn't need to use the `max-width` because the last `<p>` is wrapped. Instead, the wanted result is to use the width that the bottom `<div>` uses (~`140px`).

How can I use the preferred width and still get the item to wrap?

```css
div {
  max-width: 200px;
  width: fit-content;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 8px;
  background-color: green;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

p {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    test
  </p>
  <p>
    this is a long text
  </p>
  <p>
    short text
  </p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>
    test
  </p>
  <p>
    longer text
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: you cannot do this

Answer (score -1):

If my understanding of the question is correct, you can achieve this by using the `flex-basis` on the `p` elements instead of `max-width` on the `div` :

```
div {
  min-width: 140px;
  width: fit-content;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 8px;
  background-color: green;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

p {
  flex-basis: auto;
  background-color: red;
}
```